# Saving HTML from website with image src intact?

Tags: html, browser

I have a simple HTML file that sits on my website.  I use this with `<div contenteditable="true">`  sections and I edit the content on the fly and send it as an HTML email.

If something goes wrong, I save the file as HTML in case I need to retrieve the message sent on any given day.

The problem is saving the HTML from the browser to you computer will save the images and change the `src` in the file to that location in your directory.  I'd like to avoid this behavior since:

1. I don't want copies of the same images saving every single day.
2. If I need to resend I can just open up that file from my computer, copy, and send in an email easily.  But if I delete them from my computer, then the new `src`'s will point to the wrong place.

So is there a way to tell Chrome not to alter the HTML when it saves and to not save images?

Comment: When save HTML page, you can select `format` as `Webpage, HTML only` to save the HTML file itself. No image/css/js files would be saved and img src would be intact.

Answer (score 0):

Type `ctrl-u` on Firefox or Chrome to view html source, then copy and paste to your text editor. Save file with html extension.